# v-pre on custom component with slots

Tags: vue.js

I have just updated Vue.js from version 2.5.17 to 2.5.22, and it broke some of my code:

**PUG**

```
ssh-pre(language="html-vue" v-pre).
    &lt;div v-for="i in 3" :key="i"&gt;{{ i }}&lt;/div&gt;
```

With Vue version 2.5.17 it was calling my component `ssh-pre` and now it does not anymore in version 2.5.22 (looks like a fix https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/8376, and according to the docs it was meant to be like this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre.

So now, how can I get my component to be called, without interpreting moustaches and not adding a child element in `ssh-pre` as all the content is a slot to be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit more complicated to read but it does the trick and does not modify the rendered text: just put the escaped curly brackets inside a string inside moustaches!

```
ssh-pre(language="html-vue" v-pre).
    &lt;div v-for="i in 3" :key="i"&gt;{{ '\{\{ i \}\}' }}&lt;/div&gt;
```